# Trigonometric functions and linear dependence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

It is known that functions $1,\, \sin \omega x, \,\cos \omega x,\, \sin 2\omega x, \,\cos 2\omega x,\, \dots, \,\sin n\omega x, \,\cos n\omega x, \dots$  where $\omega = \dfrac{2 \pi}{b-a},\;$ are linearly independent on $\,[a, b]$.

Is it possible that they are **linearly dependent** for some $I \subset [a,b]$?

Answer (score 0):

For every open section I consider the solution for the ODE:
$ y'' + \lambda^2*y = 0 $ with initial conditions based on the I you picked. (pick $\lambda $ as a natural number)
the solutions are $ y(x) = a*sin(\lambda*x) + b*cos(\lambda*x)$, for $a, b$ some parameters based on the initial conditions. 
The two solutions are linearly independent (by being two solutions for the ODE) and therefore will stay so for every I (just change the initial conditions)